How to monitor the value of a hardware wallet
Suppose I have a hardware wallet with 1 BTC. Every time I connect that wallet, I can see I have 1 BTC and it has the value of 50.000 EUR.
In this case it is easy to monitor the value, as it is exactly the exchange rate, as long as I have 1 BTC.
But if I only have .07483 BTC, is there a convenient way to keep track of the value in EUR or USD without having to calculate manually?
Is there a tracker where I can monitor the wallet when knowing the exact BTC value or by entering the BTC address (is it the public key?)?

Nearly any explorer will have close-to-realtime fiat values for your BTC. However, that does typically require the entirety of your balance to be present in a single address (although some explorers do support the use of extended public keys, often with some limitations on the gap limit/number of addresses scanned).
A more comprehensive approach is to import your wallet as a watch-only wallet in an application such as Electrum - this has a couple of benefits over just use an explorer:

It will automatically track all addresses associated with your wallet, and update as transactions are made
It supports multiple fiat currency conversions, with multiple exchange rate sources

Of course, many hardware manufacturers also support similar functionality - for instance, both Trezor Suite and Ledger Live allow you to retain a watch-only wallet for your Bitcoin addresses that can be used to track its value and balances even without having the physical device connected.
